# How do you format the y-axis and the tooltip value?

Tags: chartkick

Is there a way to format the numbers on the y-axis the tooltip value? Ex, I want the numbers to be delimited by commas. 1000 -> `1,000`. `1000000` -> `1,000,000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `thousands` option for this:

```
<%= line_chart data, thousands: "," %>
```